# BigQuery async streaming data to one table

Tags: google-bigquery

I used  `tabledata().insertAll(`) method to stream my data into BigQuery.
Data are sent from TaskQueue and async are send concurrent data to one table. All pass success, but not all data are available in given table.

My question is how to async export data to BigQuery?

I use the following code to export data to BigQuery:

```
val content = TableDataInsertAllRequest().setRows(requestRows)
val tabledata = bigquery.tabledata()
var response: TableDataInsertAllResponse

try {
  response = tabledata.insertAll(projectId, dataset, table, content).execute()
  var insertErrors: List<TableDataInsertAllResponse.InsertErrors>? = response.insertErrors

    if (insertErrors != null && insertErrors.isNotEmpty()) {
      val errors = insertErrors.map { "${it.index}       ${it.errors[0].reason}      ${it.errors[0].message}" }.joinToString { "\n" }
      log.info(errors)
      throw RuntimeException("Streaming rows to BigQuery  dataset $dataset table $table fails")
    }
  }

  log.info("streaming finish")

} catch (e: IOException) {
  throw RuntimeException(e)
}
```

Comment: It might be helpful if you share the code you use for inserts.

Comment: the code snippet is added.

Comment: I don't see any obvious problems with the code, it looks ok. Maybe double-check that the insertIds are unique? Does it reproduce on a new table?

Comment: Yes. In new table problem is same. If i call twice insertAll all data are exported.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are not setting properly `insertId` and data is removed during the streaming phase. Make sure that for every unique row you have different `insertId`.

There is a streaming buffer phase and data will be persisted once all internal nodes finish their process.

You might see on the web UI

> This table has records in the streaming buffer that may not be visible in the preview.

Streamed data is available for real-time analysis within a few seconds of the first streaming insertion into a table. Data can take up to 90 minutes to become available for copy and export operations.

Comment: Yes. I am sure about the uniqueness of every row. About message i made directly query ```SELECT * FROM [testapp:dataset_test.test_table] LIMIT 1000``` and receive information, but i expect to be saved 20 cell and they are 15. The data from first request is missing.

Comment: repeat in a new table and check the error messages, a DONE response by the API it means it finished, but individual rows might have failed because of incompatible data type